# Why isn't my list centered like my logo text?

Tags: html, css

My CSS looks like so:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 1em;
}

#page {
width: 96%;
}

#logo {
height: 5%;
}

#logo h1 {
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}

#logo h2 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.9em;
}

#menu ul{
text-align: center;
}

#menu li{
display: inline;
}

#content {
padding-left: 4%;
float: left;
}
```

And then my HTML is:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<div id="logo">
    <h1>Sample Text Logo</h1>
    <h2>A Sample Catch Phrase</h2>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

However when I run this, my list is ever so slightly right of the center compared to my `H1` and `H2`. Sorry if this is a dumb question I am new to programming websites and I am trying to make one for a competition in 3 months.

Comment: Because not everything is `0` if not specified. `<ul>` and `<li>` carry default `display`, `padding` and `margin` settings with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are is default padding applied to `ul`, you need the following:

```
ul {
padding:0;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/guqfq3k0/)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to [reset your CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

You can do this by pasting the CSS in the above link at the  very top of your stylesheet.

This will remove browser defaults, such as padding on the `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I marked the other as correct because it was quicker but I like this too :D

Comment: @user1486297 - i hope you have implemented the CSS reset anyways, because it does indeed help you code from a blank sheet!